# Unable to restart mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to restart my MongoDB service with

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

But I am getting this message

```
sudo: unable to resolve host mongodb-3: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Could it be a problem with my VM?

Comment: Add the name to your `/etc/hosts` resolving to 127.0.0.1

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost this is what i have in /etc/hosts

Comment: Put a space after localhost and add `mongodb-3`

Comment: I cannot change it because it says permission denied but when I go with sudo it opens like a new file and not the previous one. @Gerhard

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/hosts` must work, unless you do not have sudo permissions to edit it. In that case, ask your systems Administrator to add it for you.

Comment: @Gerhard why do you think or how do you know `mongodb-3` is the name of the host?

Comment: How does your service file look like? Do you see any errors in the mongod logs?

Comment: because it says it right there in the error, @WernfriedDomscheit. Have seen this mutliple times, adding the name to `/etc/hosts` resolves the name and it works.

Comment: @TheParrot12345, so did you speak to your System admin yet?

Comment: I m  the system admin myself lol! But yeah it fixed the issue thank you, you can answer the question so i can upvote it and mark it as correct.